# A King and a President?

Tags: form-of-government

What kind of government would I have if there was a Republic with an elected president as-well as a hereditary monarch?

Comment: Is there any more detail that is important to you?  Plenty of republics have had monarchs and plenty of monarchies have had elected leadership also.  Just wondering if you can flesh out the idea a bit more.

Comment: Yeah, basically the monarch isn't just ceremonial they also have power just not absolute.

Comment: Great Britain - ok, they call the chief executive "Prime Minister" rather than President, but the office is fundamentally the same.

Comment: Had your question not said *hereditary*, this would've been a good fit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican_City#Political_system

Comment: Spain is just that and as they say in an answer it is called "Constitutional Monarchy". Check how works in Spain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_of_Spain

Comment: There are lots of constitutional monarchies (UK, Spain, Netherlands, Sweden, Japan...) but in all of them, the monarch does not make political decisions except in highly unusual circumstances. So for practical purposes, these monarchies probably qualify as "just ceremonial". See my answer for examples which may be more relevant.

Comment: An important distinction between a president and a prime minister overlooked by many answers below is that a president is a head of state, while a prime minister is a head of government.  A prime minister is always has some form of higher head of state above them, even if the head of state is largely ceremonial (i.e. constitutional monarchies and parliamentary systems).  A monarch is always some such head of state, with or without actual political power.  A president is also always head of state, but variously is (the US) or is not (France, Germany) the head of government also.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Is your intention that "president" be interpreted in the narrow sense which @user213305 describes or in the broad sense of "a role whose official title is President" as Ivan and Patrick Berntsen have clearly understood it?

Comment: Yes, as user213305 described it.

Comment: A monarch is the head of state, so that the president as head of state would be a contradiction. Since the definition of the difference between a monarch and a president is the method of choice of the official head of state, your question is meaningless.

Comment: If there is a hereditary monarch of any kind it is not a republic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows lack of preliminary research and the answer is trivial.

Comment: How can a republic have a hereditary monarch?  By definition, a republic has no monarch.

Comment: I mean a President and a King existing side by side.

Answer (score 6):

In the Netherlands we have both a Prime Minister (Minister-President Mark Rutte) as well as a hereditary monarchy (Koning Willem-Alexander van Oranje Nassau), a so-called **"Constitutional Monarchy"**.

The monarch has a role in politics as the one who swears in ministers and signs bills and international treaties, altough it is almost unheard of for them to to deny executing these activities when they've been approved by the ministers.

They are also responsible for reading the "troonrede" on "Prinsjesdag" (Free translations: "Throne-speech" & "Princes-day"), which explains the governing agreements the ministers have decided upon for the coming year.

Next to that they are briefed weekly on all matters of state by the prime minister and he is free to call upon other ministers to talk politics, but it is unknown if the monarch actually tries to influence policy during these talks.

[Source (In Dutch)](https://www.kabinetvandekoning.nl/wat-doen-wij/werkzaamheden-koning).

[Wikipedia (In English)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarchy_of_the_Netherlands).

### Extra Info

Recently there've been noises to move the Netherlands to a republic and be rid of the royal family, but most dutch people see the royal family as rather charming ("quaint" even), so most likely that isn't going anywhere.

Up until 2012 the monarch was also the one who appointed the person in charge of forming a coalition after elections, but since then that power has been moved to the elected officials.

Answer (score 5):

A historic example would be the UK between about 1721 (when the office of [Prime Minister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Prime_Ministers_of_the_United_Kingdom) took shape) and 1837 (accession of [Queen Victoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Victoria)). The monarch often took an [active role](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_IV_of_the_United_Kingdom#Reform_crisis) in politics, but shared power with an elected Prime Minister and Parliament.

A contemporary example is Morocco, which is undergoing a gradual [transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_of_Morocco) from an absolute monarchy, to a constitutional monarchy similar to the modern UK.

Comment: Neither of those are republics. Morocco has never been a republic. The UK was briefly a republic following the Glorious Revolution in the late 1600s, but then the monarchy was restored and it ceased to be a republic.

Answer (score 3):

> What kind of government would I have if there was a Republic with an
>   elected president as-well as a hereditary monarch?

This question is based upon a false premise.

A government with a king, even a constitutional monarch in a constitutional monarchy, is not a republic. A [republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic) is a government that does not have officials who are selected on a hereditary basis, by definition:

> A republic (Latin: res publica) is a form of government in which the
>   country is considered a "public matter" – not the private concern or
>   property of the rulers – and where offices of state are elected or
>   appointed, rather than inherited. It is a form of government under
>   which the head of state is not a monarch.

Comment: This is the only correct answer.

Comment: That definition is based upon a false premise: namely the assumption that a country has no more than one head of state.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The existence of a monarch is the defining aspect of a "constitutional monarchy", a term that doesn't say much about the nature of that constitution. Also the definition quoted expressly states that the "*offices* of state are elected or appointed, rather than inherited."

Answer (score 2):

You would have a [diarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diarchy). The closest current analogue to the situation you describe is probably Andorra, which has two heads of state, one of whom is elected (although not by the Andorran people but by the French: the President of France is *ex officio* a co-prince) and the other not (the bishop of Urgell, appointed by the Catholic church, is *ex officio* the other).

Comment: I guess a diarchy would be what I'm looking for since they're both the leaders of the country, but what would I describe it as if I wanted people to know it was also a Republic?

Answer (score 0):

In comparative politics this state might be called a [semi-democracy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-democracy).

In some older typologies states were either a republic or a dictatorship,  but those models did a bad job dealing with a lot of states which had some elements of both.  The semi-democracy is one solution to that problem.